# Bad authentication - MySQL Workbench to serverless Aurora via Cloud9

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, mysql-workbench, amazon-aurora

I'm trying to connect to AWS Aurora Serverless, using MySQL Workbench via a Cloud9 IDE instance, but am getting the following error when I test the connection using MySQLWorkbench:

```
Authentication error. Please check that your username and password are correct and try again.
Details (Original exception message):
Bad authentication type, the server is not accepting this type of authentication.
Allowed ones are:
 [u'publickey']
```

I'm able to connect to Cloud9 instance via SSH, using iTerm on my Mac. I did this by creating a openssh format public and private key set using the below, and copying the id_rsa.pub to the authorized_keys file on the Cloud9 instance:

```
ssh-keygen -o -b 4096
```

Once SSH'ed into the Cloud9 instance I was able to connect to Aurora completely fine, using:

```
mysql --user=... --password -h <aurora host>
```

But doing the same in MySQLWorkbench returns the error mentioned above. I'm completely stumped why MySQLWorkbench fails were iTerm doesn't. Any ideas please?

Double and triple checked usernames. For SSH'ing I am using ec2-user@

My needs are:
Have a MySQL database on AWS.
Minimise costs when resources are not being used
Minimise management effort to turn off resources when they are not being used
Be able to use user-friendly tools like MySQLWorkbench.

I am using Aurora Serverless for reasons 1, 2 and 3. However, Aurora Serverless can only be accessed from within a VPC, hence I will need something like a jumpbox/bastion host.

I am using Cloud9 because it can be configured to turn off its EC2 instances after 30mins of activity. This protects me from accidentally forgetting to turn off the jumpbox/bastion, and incurring costs.

I could use EC2 with an autoscaling group with minimum 0; not yet explored, I wanted to use Cloud9 as both an IDE and a jumpbox (because a common use-case is for me to develop lambda code while at the same time administering the database using MySQLWorkbench).

Thanks

Comment: Can you share how you're connecting to your Aurora using Workbench?

Comment: Here's a screenshot: https://qazeupsnfyyczpdz.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/MySQLWorkbench.png

Comment: Can you clarify: 
1. Where do you see the error
2. Why are you trying to connect to the Cloud9 EC2 instance to get to Aurora?
3. Why are you trying to connect Workbench to the database over SSH?

Comment: 1: MySQLWorkbench shows the error in a popup when I click "test connection". 2 & 3: I've updated the question with why, i.e. my "requirements" as a user